# Is there a way I can listen to firebase onChildAdded Event and respond to that in all of the screens in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a problem where I have to listen to firebase child added event in all parts of application (in all screens) and push a new screen when a child is added. I listened for firebase in the initState() method of all widgets and achieved the same result, however I don't think it's very good idea. Is there a way I could listen for firebase event in one place and push the screen when the event is triggred? It's a calling application so I want to show a screen that displays someone is calling when firebase event is triggered. Also, the app should be able to show the incoming call screen when it's in the background(paused). And if the screen is locked, It should be able to auto awake the screen. Anything would be helpful.

Comment: This is an issue you will run into when trying to do internet connection management and other situations where you may want to notify the user wherever he is. An alternative to what you are doing would be to send to your StateManagement solution, or an InheritedWidget that you might be using, the context of your current view so that it knows what context it needs to use to push a new view to the navigator.

Comment: could i use provider instead of inherited widget? and for auto awaking the device when the app is running in background but device is  locked part?

Comment: Auto waking the device is something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution with an InheritedWidget that wraps around your whole application, to which you can pass your current context and then at any moment call from outside the current view to trigger a navigation or anything else:

Make sure to wrap your whole `MaterialApp` with the InheritedWidget:

```
return InheritedState(
  child: MaterialApp(
    body: MainView()
  ...
  )
);
```

Then you make sure it has the right context by calling it on the `didChangeDependencies` method override of your stateful widget:

```
class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainViewState createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    InheritedState.of(this.context).loadContext(this.context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Navigate with InheritedWidget'),
        onPressed: () {
          InheritedState.of(context).navigateAway();
        }),
    );
  }
}

class NewView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('New view from inherited widget'),),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Test view')
      )
    );
  }
}

class InheritedState extends InheritedWidget{
  InheritedState({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);
  BuildContext _buildContext;

  void loadContext(BuildContext buildContext){
    _buildContext = buildContext;
  }

  void navigateAway(){
    Navigator.of(_buildContext).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context){
        return NewView();
      })
    );
  }

  static InheritedState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<InheritedState>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;
}
```

*If instead of just a method to be called you have a listener that triggers what you want, then you should be able to use the same code.*

Comment: I am listening to firebase event in paused state of app. If i perform print(event.snapshot.value) inside of the app, it works. Is there any way, instead of print, I could bring a screen pop up?

Comment: If you have the context, as I explained in my answer, yes, you should be able to Navigate to a new view, show a dialog or anything else you want.

Comment: The context becomes null if I pause the app i.e put it in background..any ideas what could be done?

Comment: I haven't tried that myself, but you will have to have a package that listens to the resume of the app and get the current Scaffold's context to use.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i auto awake device when a notification is fired to the device?

Comment: @UjwalKadariya The device does that itself when a notification is received, you can't control the device directly. Did my answer help solve you question?

Answer (score 0):

I use listeners in my app in this exact way, although I use the trigger to update things rather than navigate to another screen. My app is structured so that I navigate from the home page (not main.dart) to all other pages which can each have its own sub pages. I then navigate back, ultimately to the home page. I therefore only have to set up the listeners in the initState of the home page and dispose them there if I logout. They therefore remain active and responsive in all pages.